# Graph drawing fast

Tags: graphs

What is the fastest method to draw petersen graph (as given on Wikipedia) in latex, only with tikz preferably??

Actually it took me around an hour to precisely find the coordinates using sin72° , cos72° , sin36° and cos36°. Can you tell me how to do it efficiently??

Comment: The quickest way may be to look up other the answers other got in : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207953, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461655, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209125, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432545, and so on. As for your question about `sin72°`, `tikz` understands polar coordinates such as `(72:1)`, where `72` is the angle and `1` the radius. The perhaps more structured way is to use the graph drawing libraries of Ti*k*Z (or perhaps MetaPost).

Comment: Also: [Q654486](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/654486)